# I'm installing Angular CLI but I have this problem, I'm not even able to open my previous projects

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-fetch-npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@schematics/angular
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@schematics/update
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-fetch-npm
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-fetch-npm'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-fetch-npm'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-fetch-npm'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-fetch-npm'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vijaysiva/.npm/_logs/2020-07-13T16_12_54_926Z-debug.log
```

Comment: which os are you using? it looks like a permission issue.
if other than windows try installing using sudo

Comment: Hi bro thanking you so much for your concern im using mac OS Catalina 10.15.5...

Answer (score -1):

Add sudo in front of the command:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```